# Pdfbox signing and protecting without saving in filesystem

Tags: java, encryption, pdfbox, signature

Does pdfbox supports signing on runtime after generating and protecting the pdf. Currently I am successful in loading from file system and accomplishing this .

I am trying to sign the protected pdf on the fly and return the resulting doc without saving it again, making no presence of pdf saving mechanism throughout the process.

```
public byte[] attachPdf(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PDDocument doc = sign(generatedPdf());//generated pdf
    doc.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
    response = new ResponseEntity<>(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    doc.close();
}


public PDDocument sign(PDDocument doc1){
        //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signFile);
        //PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile, "*******");
        //doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        doc1.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        int accessPermissions = SigUtils.getMDPPermission(doc);

        PDSignature signature = null;
        PDRectangle rect = null;

        if (signature == null)
        {
            // create signature dictionary
            signature = new PDSignature();
        }

        if (rect == null)
        {
            rect = createSignatureRectangle(doc, humanRect);
        }
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setName("test");
        signature.setLocation("testL");
        signature.setReason("testR");
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        SignatureInterface signatureInterface = isExternalSigning() ? null : this;
        signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
        signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, doc.getNumberOfPages()-1, rect, signature));
        signatureOptions.setPage(doc.getNumberOfPages()-1);
        doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);
        //doc.save(baos);
        //doc.saveIncremental(fos);
        //IOUtils.closeQuietly(signatureOptions);
        return doc;
        }
```

Comment: No, it isn't possible. The code always reads from the existing PDF and from the incremental part to create its signature. (It is theoretically possible and I have seen such PDFs, but they were not created by PDFBox)

Comment: In theory, you could start by loading a small PDF without pages, and then put your whole work as incremental. You just have to take care that all your changes are marked for update, which would be quite a pain.

Comment: Is it possible to save by creating a in-memory file like using ByteArrayOutputStream instead of physical file system one ?

Comment: Yes. However PDFBox creates a local file from it internally. (It may be possible to load from a byte array from that ByteArrayOutputStream which is faster than from a ByteArrayInputStream, but I haven't tested whether this works for signing => try it)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working !signing is successful but upon opening it , i get a signature error . Is there some workaround for this ?

Comment: I just tried and it works: `ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        IOUtils.copy(in, baos);
        in.close(); PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(baos.toByteArray()); ` and then sign that one.

Comment: But inputFile is physical file right .I am trying without physical file by passing the doc as reference for signing.Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes it is a file, but I copied that file into a ByteArrayOutputStream, and then opened that one as a byte array, then signed it. This would be similar to you saving into a ByteArrayOutputStream and then opening its byte array. That is faster then using a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: Yes. That will work unless it is a file . In my case as i said i am not saving any file after creating pdf and sending that reference directly for digital sign then converting the doc as byteArray. Example -

`ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDDocument doc = generatefile();//file creation on the fly not saving anywhere in fs.
digitalSign(doc).save(byteArrayOutputStream);//sending that reference for sign.
sysout(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());`

Comment: No, you have to call `PDDocument.load(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())` and then sign as in the examples, i.e. modify the code accordingly.

Comment: First, i apologies if this chat goes long.
I understand to pass the doc as byteArray and do the signing which again works for file saving without issues but if i pass the doc reference after signing and convert it into byteArray for attaching it in email , I have signature error upon downloading. Included my code snippet above. Please provide any suggestion if i have missed out anything to change.

Comment: That is something different again. If you want to save the **signed** document into a byteArray, then do also call `saveIncremental` (in the signing code) with a (new!) `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Don't reuse the old object.

Comment: Yes tried that as well . It did not work and throws error while opening file in signature(error creating temporary file if I validate signature). It works only when if I use FileOutputStream and saveIncremental. Note : I am sending this bytearray as attachment to mail .

Comment: Great it worked . I am sure i tried this earlier but somehow overlooked it. Thanks @TilmanHausherr

Answer (score 1):

- As suggested changed to new **ByteArrayOutputStream** object and used
  **saveIncremental** method made it work. Snippet below.

---

```
public PDDocument sign(PDDocument doc1){
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     doc1.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
     PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
     int accessPermissions = SigUtils.getMDPPermission(doc);

     //sign doc here
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     doc.saveIncremental(baos);
     IOUtils.closeQuietly(signatureOptions);
     return baos.toByteArray();
}
```